# How to execute a query using Superset REST API?

Tags: sql, rest, apache-superset

The bearer token is set correctly in the header.

[image]

The result of the query written in the request body should be returned in the response.
Is there any configuration required in the `superset_config.py` file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.